# Calculate total values from select elements by looping through

Tags: jquery, loops

I want to loop through some elements extract there value and calculate the total value of all integers. See my code below:

```
jquery('select').each(function(){
            var total = jquery(this).attr('val');

            if (total){

                total += parseInt(total);
                console.log(total);
            }
        });
```

The code just returns the selected value twice, no calculation done.

Comment: you need to make the 'total' as number before adding as 'total' you are getting is string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should move the `total` variable outside your loop:

```
var total = 0;

jQuery('select').each(function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).attr('val');

    if (value) {
        total += parseInt(value);
    }
 });

 console.log(total);
```

Also it's worth mentioning that `val` is not a pretty standard HTML attribute. Maybe you wanted to actually use the selected value in which case you could use:

```
 var value = jQuery(this).val();
```

Also notice that `jquery` should probably be `jQuery`, don't forget that javascript is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Thx dude, it works! jQuery or jquery depends on safemode :var jquery = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

```
var total=0;
jquery('select').each(function(){
           total += Number(jquery(this).val());
});
```